# Stretch glute without injuring knee

Tags: stretching, glutes

I have tight glutes and have been stretching using several poses, mainly pretzel and figure 4. However I have been getting pain in the outside of my knees doing these stretches.

How can I stretch my glutes without hurting my knees?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: Best guess, someone was worried that this was asking for "medical advice". But we may never know.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ask a trainer or physical therapist type person. Even just asking a personal trainer for 30 seconds of free advice in a gym would probably be fine. I'll hit those guys up sometimes when I need someone to check my form.

Generally when you feel pain in your knee during a stretch it's because you're performing it incorrectly. Some very subtle differences in angles and form can be all that's needed. But trying to describe that in writing is tough.

Comment: Did you mean " Generally when you feel pain in your knee during a stretch it's because you're performing it **in**correctly"?